# Visual Studio Crashes on Opening of Solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, crash

I have a Visual Studio solution that is a web project. Every time I open it, it crashes. The application event logs reveal the following:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException
Stack:
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__4(System.Object)
 at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
 at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
 at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
 at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
 at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
 at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
 at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
 at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
 at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
 at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
 at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
 at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
 at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

And additionally:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: devenv.exe
P2: 12.0.31101.0
P3: 54548724
P4: mscorlib
P5: 4.0.30319.34014
P6: 52e0b679
P7: 254
P8: 10
P9: System.ArgumentException
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\scotth\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_devenv.exe_5210fe8fe3793329689039d226cf501d40539fff_e1d76106_1ac55aa6
```

The solution seems to open on other branches of this repository, but not master. What is causing the consistent crash and what can I do to remedy it?